# VSTS Azure service connection key rotation?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

If the service principal is created through VSTS, Is there a key rotation needed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can check the expires day as follows:

1. Log on azure portal and switch to corresponding AD
2. Click Azure Active Directory
3. Click App registrations
4. Select All apps
5. Click the corresponding application (the application name likes {vsts account}-{team project}-{subscription id})
6. Click Settings
7. Click Keys
8. Check expires day

Comment: Is there any warning this is going to happen, or are all our deploys just going to start failing one day?